# Drag & Drop com jQuery não coloca o elemento na DIV certa

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Estou tentando realizar a troca de duas imagens quando um usuário clica em uma imagem e arrasta até a outra.

Porém, o meu código não coloca as imagens na posição correta, ele deixa a imagem de destino no mesmo lugar e põe a imagem que foi arrastada na `<div>` seguinte, sobrepondo uma outra imagem.

```js
$(".elemento").draggable();
$(".containerImg").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var dropped = ui.draggable;
    var droppedOn = event.target;
    $(dropped).css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    $(droppedOn.querySelector('img')).css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(dropped.parent());
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="painel-tabuleiro">
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/1.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/1.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/1.png"/></div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/2.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/2.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/2.png"/></div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/3.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/3.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/3.png"/></div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/4.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/4.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/4.png"/></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não recomendo que utilize o draggable que é somente para movimentar os elementos. Tente utilizar o Sortable. Pode ajudar mais que o draggable: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Eu tentei o sortable, mas não consegui trocar os elementos entre as divs, apenas os elementos das proprias divs mesmo

Comment: Henrique, coloquei na resposta, mas veja esse fiddle e veja se é esse o resultado que vc tá buscando: https://jsfiddle.net/ndelavi/w7k1re0v/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseado nos nossos comentários, dei uma olhada por aí na internet sobre o `Sortable` e encontrei esse post no Stack em Inglês:

[StackOverflow in English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895625/how-do-you-use-jquery-sortable-to-sort-table-cells-in-all-the-tables-rows)

Basicamente você vai usar o `Sortable` dentro de uma `table` e modificar seu CSS para utilizar o `inline-block` para fazer

Aqui está o jsFiddle pra você se basear e ver funcionando:

[table + sortable](https://jsfiddle.net/ndelavi/w7k1re0v/16/)

**Aqui o código:**

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 330px;
    font-size: 0;/* eliminate spaces between TRs/TDs */
}
tr {
    display: inline;
}
td {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    border: 0;
    border: 3px solid white;
    font-size: 20pt;
    color: white;
    line-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.dnd-highlight {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px dashed red;
    background: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('table').sortable({
    items: 'td', 
    placeholder: 'dnd-highlight'
});
```

Você vai ter que modificar de acordo com a sua necessidade, mas a ideia é essa.

Comment: Não era bem o que eu procurava mas mudei a estrutura do projeto e isso me ajudou muito. Obrigado :)

Comment: Por nada Henrique, que pena que não deu pra usar o draggable, mas como eu disse eu fortemente recomendo o sortable pra esses casos. Com esse exemplo eu decidi até mudar o meu sortable de um dos meus projetos hahaha.

Comment: A resposta é interessante mas tem um problema que eu não sei como resolver para se adequar à minha situação, Se eu arrasto o [1] para o lugar do [3], quem assume a posição anterior do [1] é o [2] e não o [3]... tem como resolver com Sortable?

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro vc está querendo que o Sortable aja com as divs não próximas neh? Vou ter que analisar aqui cara... Sincero que eu não sei te falar assim de cara. Perai que vejo.

Comment: isso @NDelavi , eu consegui resolver, veja o exemplo: https://codepen.io/jo-o-santos/pen/rorEoo

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro muito bom cara, pelo que eu tava vendo aqui só teria desse jeito mesmo, tratando os eventos. Que bom que conseguiu! =)